# Why isn't the constructor called the second time?

Tags: python-2.7, inheritance, copy-constructor

Why isn't the constructor called the second time?

```
from datetime import datetime

class Time(datetime):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        print 5, args
        try:
            d = args[0]
            print 8, d
            datetime.__init__(self,
                d.year, d.month, t.day, t.hour, t.minute, t.second)
        except Exception:
            print 12, args
            datetime.__init__(self, args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Time(1965, 1, 10)
    print 17, t
    u = Time(t)
    print 19, u
```

Using python 2.7.2, here's the output:

```
bash-4.1$ python tmp.py
5 (1965, 1, 10)
8 1965
12 (1965, 1, 10)
17 1965-01-10 00:00:00
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 18, in <module>
    u = Time(t)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

I expected to see:

```
5 Time(1965, 1, 10)
```

What function is being called if not the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the type's [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) method.

`__init__` isn't the first thing that happens when you create an object. First, the type's `__new__` method is called to actually produce the object, and then `__init__` is called to initialize it. For mutable types, `__new__` doesn't usually do much, but for immutable types like `datetime`, `__new__` generally creates the object pre-initialized, since otherwise `__init__` would have to mutate the object to initialize it.

If you want to inherit from `datetime`, you have to implement `__new__` as well as `__init__`:

```
def __new__(cls, *args):
    print 5, args
    try:
        d = args[0]
        print 8, d
        return datetime.__new__(cls,
            d.year, d.month, t.day, t.hour, t.minute, t.second)
    except Exception:
        print 12, args
        return datetime.__new__(cls, args)
```

If you want to see what `datetime`'s `__new__` does, it's visible in [`Modules/datetimemodule.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3ac1b21fbb42/Modules/datetimemodule.c#l3668). You'll have to know C and know or look up a bunch of Python C-api stuff to understand it, though.